# neo4j db.schema.visualization schema differs from actual

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In using the training graph of movies and actors, the Movies  node label has a property of title, but when using

```
call db.schema.visualization()
```

it shows a property of name but not title.  Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The meta graph returned by `db.schema.visualization()` isn't meant to show properties that are available on nodes of that type. The properties present on the meta nodes include:

- name - the label
- indexes - the properties which are indexed for the label
- constraints - the constraints present for the label

Comment: Interestingly, for the nodes of the Person label, the meta graph shows the label and the data graph shows the name of the person.  But on the Movie label, if you select name for the caption on the meta graph you get the label: "Movie", but the data graph goes blank.  If you select title for the active caption on the data graph, you get the movie title, but the meta graph caption goes blank.  Seems like it would be better to always use the property: name so that you don't end up with the confusion.